# Flag first category within group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two group indicators, cat1 and cat2. I would like to flag the first occurrences of cat2 within cat1.

What I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','x'],['a','x'],['a','y'],['a','y'],['b','y'],['b','z'],['c','z']], columns = ['cat1', 'cat2'])

  cat1 cat2
0    a    x
1    a    x
2    a    y
3    a    y
4    b    y
5    b    z
6    c    z
```

What I would like to obtain:

```
  cat1 cat2 flag
0    a    x    1
1    a    x    1
2    a    y    0
3    a    y    0
4    b    y    1
5    b    z    0
6    c    z    1
```

I have tried various versions of rolling counts in groups, but was not able to obtain the desired result.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` on 'cat1' and then call `transform` which applies a `lambda` that compares the value of 'cat2' against the first value, this will produce a boolean array which we can then convert to `int` using `astype`:

```
In [166]:
df['flag'] = df.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].transform(lambda x: x== x.iloc[0]).astype(int)
df

Out[166]:
  cat1 cat2  flag
0    a    x     1
1    a    x     1
2    a    y     0
3    a    y     0
4    b    y     1
5    b    z     0
6    c    z     1
```

Here you can see the boolean output:

```
In [167]:
df.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].transform(lambda x: x== x.iloc[0])

Out[167]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: cat2, dtype: object
```

Another method is to call [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) in the comparison:

```
In [169]:
df['flag'] = (df['cat2'] == df.groupby('cat1')['cat2'].transform('first')).astype(int)
df

Out[169]:
  cat1 cat2  flag
0    a    x     1
1    a    x     1
2    a    y     0
3    a    y     0
4    b    y     1
5    b    z     0
6    c    z     1
```